# Three groups at a round table, with adjacent and opposite seats held by differing groups

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> There are $n$ distinct seats provided around a round table and people from three different groups are invited to a party. However, no two individuals of the same group can seat beside each other or across each other ($n$ is an even number). How many distinct ways can the groups be assigned to seats?

I have calculated a few cases. For $n=2$, the answer is 6:

```
1---2    2---1
1---3    3---1
2---3    3---2
```

For $n=4$, the answer is 0, while for $n=6$ it is 42. I have tried every method I know to get a general formula and failed.

Comment: If the table is round isn't there only 2 possibility for $n=2$? I mean group 1 and group 2, group 2 and group 1 are the same solution no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to counting the number of 3-colourings of the [Möbius ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_ladder) $M_n$ (here I use the convention that $n$ denotes the number of *pairs* of vertices; the $n$ in the question becomes $n/2$ in my convention). This problem was solved in 1972 by Biggs, Damerell and Sands:

> Biggs, N. L.; Damerell, R. M.; Sands, D. A. (1972). "[Recursive families of graphs](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0095-8956%2872%2990016-0)". *Journal of Combinatorial Theory.* Series B. **12**: 123–131.

The paper is now open-access, so be sure to read it. On page 128 they state that the chromatic polynomial that gives the number of $k$-colourings of $M_n$ is
$$C(M_n,k)=(k^2-3k+3)^n+(k-1)((3-k)^n-(1-k)^n)-1$$
In particular, when $k=3$ the formula simplifies to
$$f(n)=C(M_n,3)=3^n+(-2)^{n+1}-1$$
and this is the answer to the question. I calculate a few values below.
$$\begin{align}
f(1)&=6\\f(2)&=0\\f(3)&=42\\
f(4)&=48\\f(5)&=306\\f(6)&=600\\
f(7)&=2442\\f(8)&=6048\end{align}$$